# Is component rendered twice? Is it codesandbox problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codesandbox

Here is my simple React-app:

```
let idCounter = 0;

export default function App() {
  const id = useMemo(() => {
    console.log("useMemo");
    return idCounter++;
  }, []);

  console.log("render", id);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect", id);
  });

  return id;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-bush-swky8

This is the console output:

```
useMemo
render 0
useEffect 1
```

Why in **useEffect** `id` is equal to **1**?

Seems like the component has been rendered twice, but why **useMemo** and **useEffect** haven't been called for the second time? How **id** became **1**?

Comment: I'm not sure where to start here, because there are so many things totally against how you are supposed to write React functional components. Things like `setTimeout` should not be called from within the main component body (it should be in a `useEffect` function), likewise your `useMemo` makes no sense here as its a way to memoise values and the function should be side-effect free - I have no idea what you are trying to achieve by incrementing within it. But I am not surprised that by doing strange thing you are getting strange results!

Comment: @RobinZigmond This code is written just for testing purposes! Don't blame me for using setTimeout at rendering phase, etc.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I removed setTimeout. But now you've got less information for debugging.

Comment: @J.Snow I don't think RobinZigmond meant *blaming* you, just noting, that React is sensitive to small things like these, and deviating from the "best practices" can make it produce strange results, possibly including the one you've asked about. Take no offence, we're discussing some code, not your coding style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [React Docs - Strict Mode:](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)

> Starting with React 17, React automatically modifies the console
> methods like console.log() to silence the logs in the second call to
> lifecycle functions. However, it may cause undesired behavior in
> certain cases where a workaround can be used.

Your component is indeed rendered twice but the log statements are hidden by React during the second re-render caused by `StrictMode`.

You will get the expected output if you remove the `StrictMode`.

Another option is to use a different method on `console` object for logging, such as `console.dir`.

```js
let idCounter = 0;

function App() {
  const id = React.useMemo(() => {
    console.dir("useMemo");
    return idCounter++;
  }, []);

  console.dir("render");
  console.dir(id);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect", id);
  });

  return id;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>, 
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Great! Just what I was looking for!